# How to bin an image tensor so that each pixel value is binned/bucketed into 1 of 10 values in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensor

I have a dataset of pictures as tensors with each pixel having a value between 0 and 1, and I have a set of "bins."

```
bins = [0.05, 0.15, 0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 0.55, 0.65, 0.75, 0.85, 0.95]
```

I want to return a tensor with each pixel value being its nearest bin. As in, if a pixel is 0.03 it will turn into 0.05, if a pixel is 0.79 it will turn into 0.75.

I want this to be done with tensors not numpy.

Here is it working in numpy... tensor flow however seems to be a whole different beast when it comes to iterating. I have tried tf.map_fn and tf.scan to iterate through but I couldn't get it to work.

```py
def valueQuant(picture, splitSize):
  #This is the Picture that will be returned
  Quant_Pic = np.zeros((picture.shape[0], picture.shape[1]))

  #go through each pixel of the image
  for y_col in range(picture.shape[0]):  
    for x_row in range(picture.shape[1]):
      #isolate regions based on value
      for i in range(splitSize):
        #low and high values to isolate
        lowFloatRange = float((1/splitSize)*i)
        highFloatRange = float((1/splitSize)*(i+1))
        #value to turn entire clustor
        midRange = lowFloatRange + ((highFloatRange - lowFloatRange)/2)
        #current value of current pixel
        curVal = picture[y_col][x_row]
        #if the current value is within the range of interest
        if(curVal >= lowFloatRange and curVal <= highFloatRange):
            Quant_Pic[y_col][x_row] = midRange

  return Quant_Pic
```

I was able to figure out an element wise method using only tensor flow methods.

```py
def quant_val(current_input):
    bins = tf.constant([0.05, 0.15, 0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 0.55, 0.65, 0.75, 0.85, 0.95])
    dist = tf.tile(current_input, [10])
    dist = tf.math.subtract(bins, current_input)
    absDist = tf.math.abs(dist)
    idx = tf.math.argmin(absDist)
    output = bins[idx]
    output = tf.expand_dims(output, 0)
    print("output", output)

    return output

current_input = tf.constant([0.53])
quant_val(current_input)
```

This is able to return the right answer for a tensor with a single value, but I am unsure how to extrapolate this to the larger image tensor structure. Any help would be much appreciated!!! Thank you oh kind wise ones.

Answer (score 0):

### Round approach:

This is very simple and easy, but some .5 values are round up, others down. If this is not a problem:

```
def quant_val(images): #0 to 1

    images = (images - 0.05) * 10            #-0.5 to 9.5
    bins = tf.round(images)                  #0 to 9
    bins = tf.clip_by_value(bins, 0, 9)      #possible -1 and 10 due to the remark on top
    return (bins/10) + 0.05                  #0.05 to 0.95
```

Comment: That works perfectly. I can't believe I didn't think of it. Thank you!

Comment: Dam actually it doesn't because the tensorflow round function is not differentiable. The network will not train. I'm looking for ways around that now.

Comment: So... There is probably no easy way around. I thought that was input data (then there would be no problem). You do need to let the values be approximate and differentiable. You could try (not sure about the mathematical implications) to use division by a `stop_gradients(value)` instead of rounding.